# Help with simple SQL Query

Tags: sql

#### Table A

```
Id    Name  
1     Apple
2     Mango
```

#### Table B

```
Id  Locale      Name_In_Lang
1   es-ES       Apple[Spanish]
1   it-IT       Apple[Italian]
2   it-IT       Mango[Italian]
```

Join the table and get the following output:

```
Id  Locale      Name_In_Lang        Name
1                                   Apple
1   es-ES       Apple[Spanish]      Apple
1   it-IT       Apple[Italian]      Apple
2                                   Mango
2   it-IT       Mango[Italian]      Mango
```

I have the following query...

```
Select a.id, b.locale, b.name_in_lang, a.name 
from TableA a
Left Outer Join TableB b on ( a.id = b.id)
```

... and I only get:

```
Id  Locale      Name_In_Lang        Name
1   es-ES       Apple[Spanish]      Apple
1   it-IT       Apple[Italian]      Apple
2   it-IT       Mango[Italian]      Mango
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can union your actual results with the extra rows desired like so:

```
SELECT a.id, b.locale, b.name_in_lang, a.name
FROM TableA a
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB b ON a.id = b.id
UNION
SELECT a.id, '' AS locale, '' AS name_in_lang, a.name
FROM Table a
```

The second query in the UNION will supply one row per record in table A, with an empty locale and translated name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add one row for each entry in TableA, you could just use a UNION clause:

```
SELECT 
    a.id, b.locale, b.name_in_lang, a.name 
FROM 
    TableA a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    TableB b ON a.id = b.id

UNION

SELECT 
    id, '', '', name 
FROM 
    TableA
```

That would add one entry without any locale information to your result set.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.Id, NULL AS Locale, NULL AS Name_IN_Lang, a.Name
    FROM TableA a
UNION ALL
SELECT a.Id, b.Locale, b.Name_In_Lang, a.Name
    FROM TableA a
        INNER JOIN TableB b
            ON a.Id = b.Id
ORDER BY Id, Name, Locale
```