# Help with simple SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle

#### Table A

```
Id    Name  
1     Apple
2     Mango
3     Banana
```

#### Table B

```
Id  Locale      Name_In_Lang
1   es-ES       Apple[Spanish]
1   it-IT       Apple[Italian]
2   it-IT       Mango[Italian]
```

Let us say if the user requested spanish versions then the query should return all the spanish [es-ES] verions from Table B for every record in Table A. If the spanish version is not available then simply return the corresponding record from Table A

The output should look something like -

```
Id  Locale                  Name
1   es-ES                   Apple[Spanish]      
2                           Mango
3                           Banana
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve it with and without using union?

Comment: This is identical to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773349/help-with-simple-sql-query), requesting a different type of answer. There must be a way to combine these questions for future reference...

Comment: ...but the outputs are different :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you could use a [`LEFT JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join) as follows:

```
SELECT     ta.id, tb.locale, NVL(tb.name_in_lang, ta.name) name
FROM       tableA ta
LEFT JOIN  tableB tb ON (tb.id = ta.id AND tb.locale = ?)
```

The [`NVL()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions110.htm#SQLRF00684) function lets you substitute a value when a null value is encountered.

The output for the `es-ES` locale would look like this:

```
+------+--------+----------------+
| id   | locale | name           |
+------+--------+----------------+
|    1 | es-ES  | Apple[Spanish] |
|    2 | NULL   | Mango          |
|    3 | NULL   | Banana         |
+------+--------+----------------+
```